# Python/Django return all true variables

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, if-statement

I am trying to verify a variable condition to be greater than 0 and then if so then the text variable would be true. I have a fair amount of these as notifications I want to display in my code but for the sake of my question I will only list three here is my code:

```
notifications1 = 100
if notifications1 > 1:
    text1 = [{
                    'link': 'error1',
                    'icon_class': 'fa',
                    'icon': 'fa-calendar-check-o',
                    'color': 'info',
                    'text': SINVPartMismatch.description

            }]
else:
    text1 = None

notifications2 = 50
if notifications2 > 1:
    text2 = [{
                    'link': 'error1',
                    'icon_class': 'fa',
                    'icon': 'fa-calendar-check-o',
                    'color': 'info',
                    'text': INVNoPart.description

            }]
else:
    text2 = None

notifications3 = 0
if notifications3 > 1:
    text3 = [{
                    'link': 'error1',
                    'icon_class': 'fa',
                    'icon': 'fa-calendar-check-o',
                    'color': 'info',
                    'text': INBinNoInventoryMaster.description

            }]
else:
    text3 = None

return text1, text2, text3
```

When I run this I get the error "UnboundLocalError local variable 'text3' referenced before assignment". Basically if the number is greater than 0 I want it to display the text variables and not skip any when it reaches one that is 0. I appreciate any insight on getting me in the right direction for this!

**Edit - Now when I run it thinks they are all blank and does not display the 'text' description but if I only return one text1, text2 in the return portion it will display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about Django, but I know what's wrong with your code. It is as the error says, you used `text3` before you assigned `text3`. Here's an explanation:

```
if notifications3 > 1:
    text3 = [{
                'link': 'error1',
                'icon_class': 'fa',
                'icon': 'fa-calendar-check-o',
                'color': 'info',
                'text': description
            }]

else:
    text = [{
                'link': 'error1',
                'icon_class': 'fa',
                'icon': 'fa-calendar-check-o',
                'color': 'info',
                'text': 'There are no errors!'
            }]
return text, text1, text2, text3
```

If you look at the piece of code above (which is all the code that has `text3`), you will see that `text3` will not be assigned if `notifications3 <= 1`. So how does Python return an unassigned variable? It doesn't. It returns an error.

As [@advance512](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37996001/4428725) has suggested, you could do something like:

```
text = [{}]
text1 = [{}]
text2 = [{}]
text3 = [{}]
```

Or

```
text = None
text1 = None
text2 = None
text3 = None
```

Comment: You are saying to define them as blank as a global variable?

Comment: @Zorpho If you don't, then they won't be in the right scope when you try to print them, which is where you're getting your errors. Also, I don't think it'd be global because the fact that the end of your code has a return statement implies that that's in a function, am I correct?

Comment: Yes if you see my new edit to my question it passes but it should display text descriptions for 2 out of the 3 notifications listed but it is showing that they are all blank...I don't know if since I am passing the information as a tuple that it is not displaying correctly? But if I only return one text variable if its higher than 1 it displays

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the definition of some of either `text3` or `text` depending on the value of `notifications3`, because of the `else`. Try setting a default value for both of these variables before executing your code to modify their value.